# How to generate thumbnails on Amazon S3?

Tags: php, jquery, image, image-processing, amazon-s3

I'm stuck for ideas on this one.

I'm working on a CMS that uses a file-browser to store all media file in an S3 bucket.

I have 4 options for thumbnail sizes which generate new thumbnail images from original image.  If I'm doing this server-side in PHP it's fine - I'm just at loss as to how to do this if all the original files are stored on the bucket (I want the thumbnails to be as well).

Does any have have any ideas?  I'm using PHP5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script'll need to pull the image down, manipulate it, and upload the manipulated version back to the bucket using the S3 API.

Answer (score 0):

Use imagemagick for manipulating your images. Its free and great tool.