# How to create a video thumbnail without ffmpeg or HTML5 video canvas?

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I need to create a thumbnail from a video, I have tried the below options but they didn't work for my case. I am using S3 and CloudFront.

1. ffmpeg is not supported via my hosting because I am using a shared hosting and I need to upgrade to VPS or dedicated server if I want to use ffmpeg.
2. I tried taking a screenshot from the video using HTML5 drawImage and toDataURL functions, but it is throwing SecurityError because my video file is located on Amazon CloudFront and my code is hosted somewhere else.

Is there any other option or a workaround to the second option? I don't want to upgrade my server for just the thumbnail issue.

Comment: Shared hosting probably isn't suitable for video hosting anyway - I'd say you'll find plenty of reasons to upgrade to a VPS.

Comment: I am hosting the videos on amazon s3 and CloudFront, I am just putting my code on the shared hosting where it should create the thumbnail from the video hosted on amazon and then save the thumbnail again on amazon.

Comment: Hmm, maybe ImageMagick? Many shared hosts have that. [Possible dup of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625368/amazon-s3-and-thumbnail-generation-help)?

Comment: I need to create thumbnail from video and not from image

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick can do that, I think. Try it?

Comment: Thanks. But my hosting is un-managed so I can't install it same as ffmpeg. I guess I need a client side solution if there is any.

Comment: You might be thinking that the IMagick extension is not installed. That is probably true, but `convert` is usually installed - try `exec('which convert')` to get the path, or ask your host what the path is.